# Differentiable function with non-continuous partials?

Tags: analysis

I am given the function  $f(x,y):=(x^2+y^2)\sin(x^2+y^2)^{-0.5}$ if $(x,y)≠
(0,0)$ and $f(x,y):= 0$ if $(x,y)=0$ I am now tasked with showing that this function is differentiable in the point $(0,0)$, but that the partial derivatives are not continuous. I have calculated the partial derivatives as being $$\partial_xf=\frac{2x\sin(x^2+y^2)^{0.5}(1-0.5\tan(x^2+y^2)^{-1}(x^2+y^2))}{\sin(x^2+y^2)}$$  and $$\partial_yf=\frac{2y\sin(x^2+y^2)^{0.5}(1-0.5\tan(x^2+y^2)^{-1}(x^2+y^2))}{\sin(x^2+y^2)}.$$ But how would I now show that they are not continuous in $0$?

I believe that to show that the function is differentiable in $(0,0)$ I can use that $$\lim_{h→0}\frac{(h_1^2+h_2^2)\sin(h_1^2+h_2^2)^{-0.5}}{\|h\|_2} =\lim_{h→0}\frac{(h_1^2+h_2^2)^{0.5}}{\sin(h_1^2+h_2^2)^{0.5}} =\lim_{h→0} \left( \frac{(h_1^2+h_2^2)}{\sin(h_1^2+h_2^2)^{0.5}} \right) =1$$ Is this correct? And does anybody know how to show that the partial derivatives are not continuous?

Comment: The exponent is _inside_ the sine function, i.e.,$$f(x,y) = (x^{2} + y^{2})\sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}}.$$In that vein, have you encountered the one-variable analog, $f(x) = x^{2} \sin(1/|x|)$ (and $f(0) = 0$)?

Comment: Ah okay that does make sense the notation from the book I took this question from was a little vague, and no I have not encountered that particular function but i think I can see why its derivative is not continuous in zero. Thanks for the help